# Detecting and removing tilt from barcode images using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I want to create a generic tilt detection and correction program from barcode images using Python OpenCV. Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this functionality?

See some examples of images below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xelu6.png)

I will greatly appreciate any help/guidance to achieve this functionality.

Many Thanks and
Kind Regards,
B

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a combination of `Canny()` and `HoughLines()`. Canny would detect lines, and the Hough transform creates a record containing the angle of the line.  You could then transform the image by the average detected line angle, or something like that.

Example taken from:
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('dave.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imwrite('houghlines3.jpg',img)
```

Comment: This will remove rotation, but not tilt